# WooCommerce shortcode not returning product title and price within REST API response

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

code:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myapi/v1', '/top_rated_products/', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => function ($request) {
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      echo do_shortcode('[top_rated_products]');
    },
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
  ] );
} );
```

Requesting https://example.com/wp-json/myapi/v1/top_rated_products/ shows a list of products but with only product images, no product title or price.

I need this end point to respond with rendered HTML with complete product info. And the HTML markup structure must be exactly the same to other product list on the site, that's why I tried do_shortcode() in the first place.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route('myapi/v1', '/top_rated_products/', [
'methods' => 'GET',
'callback' => 'get_top_rated_products_html',
'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
]);
});

function get_top_rated_products_html($request) {
// Use WordPress queries or custom logic to fetch the top-rated products with their titles and prices
// Replace the following lines with your actual logic for fetching the product information
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 10, // Adjust the number of products to fetch here
// Add any other query arguments as needed
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);

$html = '<div class="top-rated-products">';
foreach ($products->posts as $product) {
$html .= '<div class="product">';
$html .= '<h2>' . get_the_title($product->ID) . '</h2>';
// Assuming you are using WooCommerce, you can get the price like this:
$html .= '<p>' . wc_price(get_post_meta($product->ID, '_regular_price', true)) . '</p>';
// Add any other product information you want to display
$html .= '</div>';
}
$html .= '</div>';

return new WP_REST_Response($html, 200);
}
```

Comment: I used do_shortcode in the hope that it would render proper HTML instead of JSON, which requires rendering on the client side. This is to ensure a consistent markup structure with other product lists on the page.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't handle structured data

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you join this room ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254666/room-for-nadir-belhaj-and-shawn

Comment: Edited with correct answer